# How can I get object from tempdata in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have employee class

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmpID { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
}
```

I want the same using `TempData` on View....
if I use `@TempData["Employee"]`

I am getting modal.employee which is fair enough..

please suggest

Comment: so do you have any problems getting the data ?

Comment: `TempData` only lasts one request. Is should not be used for this type of scenario

Answer (score 7):

To set data in `TempData` -

```
TempData["Employee"] = new Employee() {Designation = "Manager"};
```

To retrieve it in view -

```
@{
    var emp = TempData["Employee"] as Employee;
}
```

Use `emp` variable in later part of the view.

```
<div>@emp.Designation</div>
```

**IMPORTANT** Any object in `TempData` will be removed once it is read (or)retrieved. To keep it in `TempData` for further usage, use `Tempdata.Keep()`

```
TempData.Keep("Employee");
```

Alternatively you can use `ViewBag` to send data from Controller to View.

Comment: Great Help :)..loved this

Comment: And then hit F5 or refresh the browser and see the exception it throws :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke :-), yes Any object in `TempData` will be removed once it is retrieved. To keep it in TempData for simultaneous usage, use `Tempdata.Keep()`

Answer (score 1):

With something like this:

```
@{Employee employee = (Employee )TempData["Employee"];}
```

Comment: Employee objEmployee = new Employee()
            {
                Name = "Nishant",
                EmpID = "aa",
                Designation = "XYM"
            };
            TempData["Employee"] = objEmployee;